# Not able to complete execution of the Firebase Init command form directory containing angularjs code

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I created a new empty app on firebase and now I am trying to initialize it. When I run the firebase init command from the directory containing my angularjs app I do not see the new app on firebase with the arrows. Just an old app and selections to create a new app or "not set up a default app".  This used to be easy as I set up 3 other apps before the new CLI  How do I associate the app on my windows directory with the new app just created in firebase?

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like you might be signed in to an old account or using an old version of the CLI.

Can you take these steps:

1. `firebase logout`
2. `npm install -g firebase-tools`
3. `firebase login`
4. `firebase init` again

Comment: Thank you Frank I tried this, but without success When I specified "do Not setup default directory, it seem to run, but here is the firebase.s=json file it built. It has no reference to the app on firebase.{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Installing latest node from node website solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed my folder and the CLI of firebase was creating the files outside the project route, I copy the build outside and run again.

- firebase deploy

And it works sending all the files to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Some times our system do not give these type of major execution permission to third part software like sublime,vs Code etc..
and firebase need some changes in our system
you can solve this by running these commands in your powersell, make sure that you are running these commands as administrator.

1. Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
2. Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
3. press : "Y"(capital Y)
4. run first command again to check that all policies are unrestricted or not
5. go back to your software and run "firebase init"

[sample-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QudcW.png)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for help Frank.. I have figured out this works. The Public directory was causing me problems So I changed firebase.json to have Public: ".". Now all the files in my root directory deploy The documentation or the prompt should say enter . for root. The documentation should also point out that you should create a project from the console before initializing a directory. I am having a problem creating projects and will post another question to Stack. Thanks for all your help.. You have been a great help to me in the past as well